# Find an equation that using Fixed Point Iteration converges to -1.02

Tags: numerical-methods, fixed-point-iteration

Let $f(x) = e^{x-2} + x^3 - x$, then using fixed point iteration, find all of the roots. I've already found two equations which converge to 0.163822 and ~0.788941.

The equation which converges toward 0.163822 is: $e^{x-2} + x^3$ with a guess of $0.1$

The equation which converges toward ~0.788941 is: $\frac{-e^{x-2} + x}{x}^{\frac{-1}{2}}$ with a guess of $1.5$.

I can't seem to find an equation which converges to the last root of approximately -1.02.

Comment: Try another initial guess. Then, the iteration might converge to that root.

Comment: The third possible function is $\ln(x-x^3)+2$

Comment: @Peter, I've tried that function, but it does not converge to -1. Is there a particular guess you had in mind? I've tried guesses of -1, 0, 0.1, and 1 and they all seem to go to infinity

Comment: The fixpoint-iteration might fail for this root. I did not find a function and a guess doing the job yet.

Comment: By the way, instead of  $0$, the third root is $0.1638$.

Comment: Yes, the root should be 0.1638, this was actually a typo on my part. I have corrected it. The equation that I claimed to converge toward 0 actually converged toward 0.1638

Comment: I would expect $x_{k+1}=x_k-\frac{e^{x_k-2}+x_k^3-x_k}{e^{x_k-2}+3x_k^2-1},x_0=-1$ to work...but maybe that is "cheating" for the purposes of your assignment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try $f(x)=\sqrt[3]{x-e^{x-2}}$, starting from a negative value. The rationale is that the cubic root has a slope less than $1$ for values less than $-1$.

[image]

$$
-2 \\
-1.26375541197 \\
-1.09195226149 \\
-1.0438385854 \\
-1.02961125511 \\
-1.02533462938 \\
-1.02404271663 \\
-1.02365186038 \\
-1.0235335567 \\
-1.02349774382 \\
\vdots$$

You can also get convergence to a positive root.

$$
1 \\
0.858222649309 \\
0.813807987157 \\
0.798134216479 \\
0.792376247446 \\
0.790229882858 \\
0.789425446205 \\
0.789123338776 \\
0.789009795416 \\
0.788967109326 \\
\vdots$$